# PL/SQL Code to fetch headcount for each month in one quarter

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have one table, per_all_peopl_f, with following columns:

```
name  person_id  emp_flag  effective_start_date   effective_end_date   DOJ
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ABC   123          Y       30-MAR-2011              30-MAR-2013       10-FEB-2011
ABC   123          Y       24-FEB-2011              27-FEB-2011       10-FEB-2011
DEF   345          N       10-APR-2012              30-DEC-4712       15-SEP-2011
```

There are many entries (1000+) with repeated data and different effective start dates.

I have to calculate the Workforce headcount. That is, the number of employees that exits the company quarterly.

The following columns have to be fetched:

```
Headcount in 2012 (1st quarter)
Headcount in 2013 (1st quarter)
difference between the two headcounts
% difference
```

The problem is the query i am using is giving the headcount of only 1 quarter.
I want that headcount is calculatd for each month in 1 quarter. That is jan ,feb,mar seperate --> q1. Apr,May,Jun -->q2 seperate.

Example :- If i pass p_quarter as  Q1.

The output shoul calculate headcount for Jan , Feb,Mar,Apr. All 4 seperately

I am not geting how to include anothr for loop and same function to fetch this date.

The query I used to find the headcount quarterly is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name
      (l_end_date ,l_start_date  ) 
      RETURN number;
      IS 
        l_emp

      BEGIN
        select count(distinct papf.person_id)
          into l_emp
          from per_all_people_f papf
         where papf.emp_flag ='Y'
           and effective_start_date >=l_end_date
           and effective_end_date <=l_start_date ;

        return l_emp; 
    END function_name;


    create xx_pack_name  body
    is 
    crate or replace procedure proc_name( l_quarter number,
                          p_person_id number,
                          l_quarter number )
        cursor cur_var
        is 
           select function_name(l_start_date ,l_end_date ) EMP_2012,
                  function_name(l_start_date1,l_end_date1 ) EMP_2013,
                  function_name(l_start_date ,l_end_date )-function_name(l_start_date1,l_end_date1 ) Diff
             from dual;


    Begin


    if l_quarter =1
    then
    l_start_date1 :='01-Jan-2013';
    l_end_dat1e :='31-APR-2013';
 l_start_date :='01-Jan-2012';
    l_end_date :='31-APR-2012';

    elsif l_quarter =2
    then
    l_start_date :='01-May-2012';
    l_end_date :='31-Aug-2012';
 l_start_date1 :='01-May-2013';
    l_end_date1 :='31-Aug-2013';


    else
    l_start_date1 :='01-Sep-2013';
    l_end_date1 :='31-Dec-2013';




    end if;

    for cur_val in cur_var 
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_var.emp_2012 || cur_var.emp_2013 ||cur_var.diff )

    end loop



    end xx_pack_name  ;
```

Comment: You know, there is a "QUARTER" formatting option available when converting a date to characters: `select to_char(sysdate,'Q') from dual;` ...it might help? ;)

Comment: Also, why does `proc_name` take *two* inputs named `l_quarter`?

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't make much sense - I'm not even sure it would compile. Either way, you can tell if a date is in a range using quarters with something like this: `select case
       when to_number(to_char(to_date('2012-03-21','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYQ')) between to_number(to_char(to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYYQ'))
            and to_number(to_char(to_date('2012-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYQ'))  then
            'Y' 
       end from dual;`

Comment: @JustinCave Also possible duplicate of [pl/SQL (How to calculate the first and last day of any quarter of any year)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18549406/272735).